# Android Gradle Plugin 8.2.2 not compatible with Coil Bom

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, coil, maven-bom

I am updating my [Android Gradle plugin](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)

```
agp_version = '8.2.2'
```

and I have an error, that was not there with older version **(was working fine with AGP 8.1.2)**

```
Failed to resolve: io.coil-kt:coil-bom:2.5.0
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain how the `Failed to resolve: io.coil-kt:coil-bom:2.5.0` error is related to Ktor?

Comment: there is no such ```io.coil-kt:coil-bom``` library available on official site.

Comment: Sorry, just update ktor to coil. As said, it works with AGP 8.1.2. @Chirag-Thummar: [coil-bom](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.coil-kt/coil-bom)

Comment: You may be missing ```mavenCentral()``` in ```settings.gradle``` or share your complete logcat.